# Update a table in ssis without using Data Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, ssis

whenever i try to update tables from source to destination tables (sql server to sql server) in ssis i run a stored procedure with the update query. i execute this SP via OLE DB Command. Now for the OLE DB command to run i have to do a Data Conversion from DT_WSTR to DT_STR.

[image]

My question is: is it possible to perform update without this data coversion? what is confusing to me is that i am pulling data from sql server and pushing data to sql server. so why is that varchar having different data enconding(DT_WSTR and DT_STR)?

But if i simply do an insert, i.e no update(use the OLE DB Command) i dont have to do any coversion and my SSIS package works fine. Now there is no problem of DT_WSTR and DT_STR but the problme occurs only when i try to run an OLE DB Command. how is ssis now inserting data from nvarchar to varchar?

[image]

i am sorry if this is a foolish question. i am quite new to SSIS.

Comment: Does your Source `SQL Azure` and `destination ` both have same data type  ?

Comment: yes they have the same table structure and data types

Comment: r u mapping the columns in `OLEDB Command` properly .This seems weird .You can double click the arrow between `SQL Azure` and `Lookup` and check the `metadata` for the column which is causing this issue

Comment: ya it have been mapped properly. This is just killing me and m so confused that its running great when i do an simple insert but if i try to do an update i m forced to do a conversion. The metadata is DT_WSTR.

Comment: I suspect that since your are using `ADO.NET` destination so it is implicitly converting from DT_WSTR to DT_STR as mentioned in `Microsoft Connect`.

Comment: could be. i need to dig it more down. this question was asked to me by our technical architect and i still dont have a solution. thanks for ur help though.

Comment: Instead of `Data conversion` you can directly cast the column in Oledb command .check my answer below

Comment: sure thanks. will be using the cast from now-onwards.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `ADO.NET` source which you are using to connect to `SQL Azure` is by default converting  `varchar` to `nvarchar`.Since at present `OLEDB` source cannot be used to connect to `SQL Azure` which in my case will give you correct column data type so you are left with using `Data Conversion`  to convert to `DT_WSTR` to `DT_STR`.

There is a [Microsft Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/425295/ssis-allow-ado-net-source-to-directly-create-output-columns-of-type-dt-str) which shows this issue with `ADO.NET` source

```
 DECLARE @column_value AS NVARCHAR(30)
 SET @column_value = ?
 UPDATE YOURTABLE 
 SET column1=convert(varchar(30),@column_value)
```

Comment: so u mean to say that i can do an update without using Data Conversion if i do from Sql Sever to Sql Server? But its not working for me.

Comment: and thanks for that link. It seems that its an issue in ssis that it converts varchar to nvarchar.

Comment: No u have to use `Data Conversion` or use `Cast` in your `OLEDB Command` like `Update table set Column=convert(varchar(10),?)`